# Default external access Setting Issue for site Guest user

Tags: apex, query, apex-sharing

If I query this record I will get one record

Query Editor & Anonymous window

```
   select id,Name from Account where Name='TestPartner'
```

but In coding,

```
        system.debug('company domain---->'+companydomainName);
        for(Account accRecord : [select id,Name from Account where 
 Name=:companydomainName]){
            system.debug('******accRecord.Id****'+accRecord.id);
 }
```

Able to get compaindomainName as TestPartner,but it will not print record Id.(Trying as site guest user)

If I make default access setting is public read/write,it works. Intially it was private.

- Whats the best way to get the value in code level,without making as private?
- I would like to know more about this issue.So if any sharing rule is it makes effect,if I make default access setting is public r/w?

Comment: Looks like you already did it. Best way without making private is to make it public read for external. If it is just needed in code you can use without sharing on the class. That will limit exposure to only code access

Comment: Okay. after chaning  sharing setting public read/write disabled.How can I revert it back

Comment: Just change it back to private...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A)**HIGH RISK** : *Give Read Only/Write Access to External User*

Making public read would also mean that Guest Site user can autoincrement ID's in URL param and access records which should not have been exposed.

B) **Using Owner/Criteria Based Sharing Rule**: This will be far better than giving External Read-only permission.

c) U**sing Without Sharing and handling all in your apex code**: As I can see you are using SOQL and thus no Standard SF functionality, it would make more sense to handle it on your own rather than giving risky sharing access